# How to log and respond with error messages from failed JWT authorisation in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, jwt, ktor

When I am authorising a request, if any of the standard claims in the JWT are invalid, or if it fails for some other reason (such as the signature being incorrect), I would like to be able to see what exactly was incorrect, especially when testing. Currently, I am not able to see any message in the `Unauthorized 401` response, nor in my logs.

My authentication setup (in my `Application.module()` function), using the auth0-jwt library.

```
    val jwtVerifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.RSA256(getPublicKeyFromString(publicKey), null))
        .withAudience("audience")
        .acceptLeeway(1)
        .acceptExpiresAt(5)
        .build()

    install(Authentication) {
        jwt {
            verifier(jwtVerifier)
            validate { credential: JWTCredential ->
                JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
            }
        }
    }

    @OptIn(KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI::class)
    install(Locations) // see http://ktor.io/features/locations.html
    install(Routing) {
        authenticate {
            ServiceEndpoints()
        }
    }
```

I have set up an endpoint handler as follows:

```
fun Route.ServiceEndpoints() {
   
    get<Paths.getData> { params ->
        checkCustomClaim(context.authentication.principal(), <some other parameters here>)
        //handling code here

    }
}
```

I'll point out that `checkCustomClaim()` will raise an AuthorisationException (just a simple exception that I created) if the custom claim fails. I do it this way because each endpoint will be checking different information in my custom claims.

I have attempted to get logs and more information in the response with a custom status page. I am able to get the log message and response data for my AuthorisationExceptions, but not for failures in the standard claims.

```
install(StatusPages) {
    exception<JWTVerificationException> { cause ->
        log.warn("Unauthorized: ${cause.message}")
        this.call.respond(
            status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            message = cause.message ?: "Unauthorized"
        )
    }
    exception<AuthorisationException> { cause ->
        log.warn("Unauthorized: ${cause.message}")
        this.call.respond(
            status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            message = cause.message ?: "Unauthorized"
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the Ktor source, it turns out to be possible to log the JWT verifcation failures with a logger for `io.ktor.auth.jwt` at the trace level. I'm still searching for a nice way to get that message into the response though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use information from a [JWT diagnostics](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/commit/c1929f919634e7d9a0720ee3e1e72e73ddf6b8b0) log that is written on the `TRACE` level.